# Поиск по маскам и добавление компьтеров в группу

Tags: powershell

Пытаюсь найти компьютеры по маскам, но у меня ничего не выводит. В последующем надо добавить в группу.
Так как я не могу найти скрипт дальше продолжить не могу.

Сама строка которая не показывает вывод и никаких ошибок, если убрать два имени по маске, то команда отрабатывает.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like ""Avtotest*, DevTrans*, VDI*""} | select name
```

Вот сам пример скрипта.

```
    $ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like ""Avtotest*, DevTrans*, VDI*""} | select name |

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
    {
       Add-AdGroupmember -Identity "VDI-Intech" -Members (Get-ADComputer $computer)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я честно говоря так и не нашел способа как указать, несколько значений для оператор сравнения like. Точно могу сказать можно сделать следующим способом:

```
$ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "'Avtotest*' -or Name -like 'DevTrans*' -or Name -like 'VDI*'"} |Select-object -expandproperty SamAccountName

Add-AdGroupmember -Identity "VDI-Intech" -Members $ComputerList
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше заменить `-like` на [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#-match-and--notmatch) и пользоваться значительно более мощными регулярными выражениями вместо WildCards.

```
> "Avtotest 1234" -match "^Avtotest|^DevTrans|^VDI"
```

```
True
```